# Github - Unable to push my code to github. It stays there in gitbash

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and git hub. My local repo is fine. I am trying to push my changes to github. I created a private repo in my github account. The URL is
https://github.com//git-tryals
(git-tryals = my repo name)

From my gitbash, I created a remote:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<myusername>/git-tryals
```

I can see that remote was created. Did the following and it stays there forever.

```
git push origin master
```

I went to the github - permissions, and changed my repo to "public". its the same behaviour. Is there anything I should do? (I am running a windows 10 machine, if that makes any difference)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Without any output error it is really difficult to help you. The public/private attribute is not relevant. Are you using the terminal provided by git or the default windows terminal?

Comment: What Git version are you running? Some Windows versions around 2.32 or so have a bug and get stuck here when using https.

Comment: There is no error, unfortunately. Just a blinking cursor. I am using gitbash.

Comment: I am using 2.32.0. It is the latest version. Do I need different version?

Answer (score 2):

This is an authorization problem. To solve the problem quickly, you can change the URL in this way:
`$ git config remote.origin.url https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME.git`
Another way I recommend is to create an **SSH key pair**.
An SSH key helps ensure a secure connection between your local repository and a secure remote repository.
This is also very useful because it saves you from having to identify yourself each time. Follow the steps below:

1. In Git Bash, run the following command to generate your SSH key pair:
   `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremail@example.com"`
2. Now press the enter key twice on the keyboard.
   Did you? Great! you've just created your SSH key pair.
3. To find it, just go to the address:
   *C:\Users\YourUsername.ssh* 
   and view the hidden folders.
4. You then have two files in this folder:
   --> your public key: *id_rsa.pub* 
   --> your private key: *id_rsa.txt* 
   You can copy your public key by opening it in a notepad.
5. Now let's see how to add the key to your GitHub account in this way:

- Log in to your GitHub space, then go to the right corner of your account and click on Settings.
- Click on the "SSH and GPG keys".
- Click on "New SSH key".
- Choose a title (for example 'personal key').
- Paste your SSH key and click on "Add SSH key".

6. Now every time you post your code you must do use this url:
   git@github.com:USERNAME/REPONAME.git 
   So:
   `$ git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPONAME.git`
   `$ git push -u origin main`
   or if you need to edit the old url (as in your case), you should do:
   `$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPONAME.git`
   `$ git push -u origin main`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did exactly that and still the same issue. Do I have to copy the private key somewhere in my local repo? How does the handshake happen?

Comment: yes you are right, I have updated the last part of the post, I hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks. Now it says git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Should I add the privte key somewhere in my command?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls shows that if my remote URL is https, i dont have to use SSH keys.

Comment: Unfortunately, this error can be caused by multiple factors, but GitHub has a specific help page for that error message: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

Answer (score 0):

Did you try add the files and committing first before pushing?

```
git add *
git commit -m "(a message)"
```

Comment: to the loca repo? Yes. I did both to the local repo.